# compress Data from listbox using ZipFile

Tags: c#

I am creating button click event, on clicking it will select data of  textbox1 and comboBox1. Further it will search for specific file type from the folder name I provide into textbox1. Currently I am using listbox1 as container for storing value from combobox and textbox. Now I want to Zip the file I got from listbox1. I am using ZipFile to compress it.Now I am stuck in how to call all data from listbox1 for compressing.

```
namespace WinDataStore
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ComboBox comboBox;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var daysOfWeek =
                new[] { "RED", "GREEN", "BLUE"
                         };           
             comboBox = new ComboBox
            {
                DataSource = daysOfWeek,
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(180, 140),
                Name = "comboBox",
                Size = new System.Drawing.Size(166, 21),
                DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
            };            
            this.Controls.Add(comboBox);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            folderBrowserDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;         
            DialogResult dlgResult = folderBrowserDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (dlgResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
            {                
                textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDlg.SelectedPath;              
               Environment.SpecialFolder rootFolder = folderBrowserDlg.RootFolder;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                //notification to user
                return;
            }

            string[] extensions = { ".xml",".ddg" };

            string[] dizin = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Where(f => extensions.Contains(new FileInfo(f).Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();

            listBox1.Items.AddRange(dizin);
            var comboBox = this.Controls["comboBox"] as ComboBox;                            
             string s = (string)comboBox.SelectedItem;
             listBox1.Items.Add(s);         


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to compress the file or the text from listbox1?

Comment: listbox1 contains data from comboBox say Red and file path C:\Users\com1.xml
C:\Users\com2.xml so basically I want to compress enitre content of listbox1

Comment: what is the problem?you can use selecteditem and if you want multiple selection then try `listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;`